# How do I compute area, perimeter, & in radius with Views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, model-view-controller

So, I'm creating an application whose main purpose is to compute the area, perimeter, and inradius of a triangle. The user is supposed to enter three values that are of type double. & whichever button they click should spit out the answer in the result view. The user can click any button (it doesn't matter which). If they click the "area" button first & then decide to click the "perimeter" button, the result should change. Here is a picture to give you an idea of what it looks like: (http://tinypic.com/r/v3ncyh/8). I'm not sure if I am programming this correctly because my values look completely incorrect & I do not think my Views are connected correctly to my code. The first section of this code is my Triangle class that contains all my getters/setters & my methods for computing the area, perimeter, and inradius. The second section is my Activity which is the main (& only) Activity for my application.

public class Triangle {

```
// instance variables
private double sideA;
private double sideB;
private double sideC;

// Getters and setters
public double getSideA() {
    return sideA;
}

public void setSideA(double sideA) {
    this.sideA = sideA;
}

public double getSide2B() {
    return sideB;
}

public void setSideB(double sideB) {
    this.sideB = sideB;
}

public double getSideC() {
    return sideC;
}

public void setSideC(double sideC) {
    this.sideC = sideC;
}

// Constructor
public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
    this.sideA = sideA;
    this.sideB = sideB;
    this.sideC = sideC;
}

// Three methods...
public double getPerimeter() {

    return sideA + sideB + sideC;
}

public double getArea() {

    double s = 1/2 * (sideA + sideB + sideC);
    double area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-sideA)*(s-sideB)*(s-sideC));

    return area;
}

public double getInRadius() {

    double r = ((-sideA + sideB + sideC)*(sideA - sideB + sideC)*(sideA + sideB - sideC))/(4*(sideA + sideB + sideC));
    double answer = Math.sqrt(r);

    return r;
}
```

}

public class TriangleComputationActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_triangle_computation);

    // Declare our View variables and assign them the Views from the layout file
    final TextView lengthOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lengthOne);
    final TextView lengthTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lengthTwo);
    final TextView lengthThree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lengthThree);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    Button areaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.area);
    Button perimeterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.perimeter);
    Button inradiusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inradius);

    final Triangle triangle = new Triangle((double)lengthOne.getInputType(), (double)lengthTwo.getInputType(),(double)lengthThree.getInputType());

    // Methods in Action...
    areaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            result.setText(triangle.getArea());

        }
    });

    perimeterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            result.setText(triangle.getPerimeter());
        }
    });

    inradiusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            result.setText(triangle.getInRadius());
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`TextView.getInputType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getInputType()) does not return a value that is useful to you. It has nothing to do with the actual text of the TextView.

You should be using `TextView.getText()` instead. You will have to convert this to a double using `Double.parseInt()` or `Double.valueOf()`. If it were me, I would set `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` on those TextViews.

Comment: Where would I do the conversion exactly? & I have already set the inputTypes to numberDecimal.

Comment: Get the text, convert to doubles, then pass the doubles to your Triangle constructor. Right now you are getting the text inside of `onCreate` and never anywhere else. You probably want some method to extract those numbers when the user presses a button, otherwise your Triangle will always have whatever values were in the text fields when `onCreate` ran.